# Openshift Throwing "Unable to retrieve the authentication details"

Tags: eclipse, openshift

While am creating openshift project in my eclipse(luna and openshift 3) its showing

> "Unable to retrieve the authentication details
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException while trying to get an authorization context for server https://console.preview.openshift.com"

Any one help me out?

[image]

Comment: It's going to be hard to help without some code or config to look at, and a clear error message from this context.

Answer (score 0):

That URL was used for the OpenShift 3 Developer Preview that was replaced by OpenShift Online Starter and OpenShift Online Pro.

You will instead need to use the console URL for the region that you're provisioned in.

For Starter, it will be one of

- https://console.starter-us-west-1.openshift.com
- https://console.starter-us-west-2.openshift.com
- https://console.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com
- https://console.starter-us-east-2.openshift.com
- https://console.starter-ca-central-1.openshift.com

For Pro right now, there is only

- https://console.pro-us-east-1.openshift.com